# How to toggle visibility of ListView ViewCell attribute on tap in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create an expandable `ListView`, with a custom `ViewCell` containing two `StackLayout`s. The first one would be the *header* and the second layout would be a children of the first one and show additional *details*. The idea is that the *details* layout would be hidden by default, and its visibility would be toggled when its `ViewCell` container is tapped.

I am not sure how to properly achieve this in the Xamarin.Forms environment, and have not found any truly helpful resource. I can imagine one solution which would involve creating a custom sub-class of `ViewCell`; or another in which I would add a visibility attribute to each item of my `ListView.itemsSource` through a ViewModel.
**What is consider best-practise in that case, and how to achieve this in Xamarin.Forms?**

---

Below is a XAML outline of what I aim to create:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True"
        ItemTapped="listView_OnItemTapped"
        x:Name="listView">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                   Padding="10,10,10,10">
        <!-- Header Stuff -->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                     x:Name="_slDetails">
          <!-- Details Stuff -->
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your looking for is GroupHeaderTemplate ,
for example :

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}"
                  Detail="{Binding ShortName}"
                  TextColor="#f35e20"
                  DetailColor="#503026" />
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

please check the following links

For information on how to use GroupHeaderTemplate : [customizing-list-appearance](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/).

Related to the toggled on click part of your question: [xamarin-forms-expandable-listview](http://www.compliancestudio.io/blog/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is not what I am after. What you are proposing enables the grouping of several cells together, and the expansion / collapse of those groups. What I want is a for every cell to have some additional information hidden by default, which can be made visible upon a tap event (and therefore resize the cell).

Comment: @PierreThalamy that's what his example does except your item would be a header. I've used that code successfully